# Grails tags that I do not understand

Tags: grails

I am working on grails trying to fix a bug in a program, however I am new to it and there are lots of codes I am trying to understand what they are. If you can direct me to the correct website that has a library explaining those kind of tags that would be wonderful

What is a `<r:script>` tag?
what is a `<g: if>` tag?

Where can I read about those? I am new to both Angular JS and Grails/Groovy

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<r:script>
        <g:if test="${module && module == 'LIVEDATA'}">
            var wsPath = "${createLink(controller: "atmosphere", action: "wssignal", absolute: true)}";
            analysis.initLiveData(device_sn, vId, debug, anlaysisType, wsPath);
            $(window).load(function() { 
                analysisToolbar.init();
                analysis.initSocket(tz);
            });
        </g:if>
    </r:script>\\
```

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/if.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<g:if>` tag is the if tag from the Grails tag library and you can read about it in the [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/if.html). This is a logical tag that will include the containing block of content when the conditions in the `test` attribute evaluate to true.

The `<r:script>` tag is the resources script tag and you can read about it in the [resources plugin documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/ref/Tags/script.html). This tag allows you to wrap inline javascript code and control it's disposition.

Both of these are tag libraries and you can read about the general concept of these in the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#taglibs) regarding them.